# Jacobian for a composition of two bilinear functions

Tags: real-analysis, bilinear-form, jacobian

Can somebody tell me what the jacobian of $f(x) = \frac{x^T C x}{a^2 + x^T C x}$ looks like and how to get there? I was thinking about using $f(x) = g(x) \cdot h(x)^{-1}$ and using the product rule, is this feasible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply the formulas $J=\nabla (F(x))^T$ and $\nabla \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)=\frac{g\nabla f-f\nabla g}{g^2}$

(see [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84518/quotient-rule-extendable-to-functions-of-vectors}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84518/quotient-rule-extendable-to-functions-of-vectors%7D)

so if $B=x^TCx$, you will get
$J=\left(\frac{(a^2\nabla B)}{(a^2+B)^2}\right)^T$

Comment: Could you also tell me what the hessians for both B as you defined it and F look like? I know how to do it entry-wise but not in a more general way